# Change file formatting using linux filters

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pipe

I am new to this shell-script programming so need your help to write a code which is efficient one.

Input file format :

```
60 00 00 00
00 90 32 20
00 00 00 00
.....
```

Output File format:

```
6000 0000 0090 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 
......
```

I want to convert input file to output file and vice-versa so need code for both sides.

Code should be in linux shell script using filters like awk,sed,grep,etc using pipe and linux redirection operators...

**Limitation**

A single line would be best otherwise as much lesser no. of lines as possible

Comment: In the future, _please_ include any previous attempt you made, however horrible or broken. This helps us to understand _exactly_ where you are stuck, which lets us write answers that not only _solve your problem_ but also _teach you something_.

Comment: @TimPost okk.. thanx for the suggestion I would definitely keep this thing in mind in future ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rather simple solution to this problem.

```
while read line; do
   block1=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1$2 }'`
   block2=`echo $line | awk '{ print $3$4 }'`
   echo "$block1 $block2 " >> outputfile
done < inputfile
```

I'm not sure if you need to insert a new line after 8 blocks, but if so, a regex like `s/(.*){32}/$1\n/g` should do the trick.

Comment: ya I do need a newline character after 8 blocks and how would you count for 8 blocks where I will substitute this regex.Please make a edit for it also ..

Comment: k sorry I think this 32 is already for its count I should have rather first tried it.Thanx n sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

It can be very simple in bash:

```
while read a b c d; do printf "%s%s " $a $b $c $d; done < file
```

If you need the newlines:

```
i=0
while read a b c d; do
    printf "%s%s " $a $b $c $d
    if (( ++i == 4 )); then 
        echo
        i=0
    fi
done < file
```

Or, with awk

```
awk '
    {printf("%s%s %s%s ", $1, $2, $3, $4)}
    NR % 4 == 0 {print ""}
' file
```